# Problems Converting Z3 to CVC4

Tags: z3, cvc4

I have a satisfiability problem written in C++ with Z3, and I'm trying to translate it to SMT-LIB2 which I'm then feeding into CVC4 to solve.

When I print the `Z3_solver` for the problem (using `Z3_solver_to_string()`), I believe it's printing in the `Z3_PRINT_SMTLIB_FULL` form, not `Z3_PRINT_SMTLIB2_COMPLIANT` (CVC4 throws a `Parse Error: unexpected token '('`).

I see in the API there's a method called `Z3_set_ast_print_mode()` to get ASTs in the right SMT-LIB form, but is there a way to do this for the `Z3_solver` type? Is the solver even the right thing to print here, or should I be printing one of the nodes and sending that to CVC4?

Comment: Stack-overflow works the best if you post "actual" code segments people can take a look and play with. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Please post a code sample illustrating the issue where CVC4 is complaining about the input it receives.